# Is there a way to load a LaunchAgent plist programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-foundation, launchd

I am looking for an alternative way asides using NSTask/system() to run "launchctl load (plist)". Is there an API for this? Something like CFLaunchdHelper or NSLaunchd. I tried searching but didn't find any and [TN2083](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2083/_index.html) doesn't have any info about this.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your launch agent? Are you looking to run a helper tool? A script? Quite possibly, there are better ways to do this than with a launch agent...

Comment: radj, have you found a solution? I'm in a similar situation, where I need to programmatically run an agent. In my case, the scheduled task need to be configurable by users at any time. So I need to create/update agents programmatically.

Comment: @mthama I think I did using the answer below. But I'm sorry I already forgot and I no longer have the codes to this as it was proprietary to a former company :/

Comment: Well... you gave an important information. You have succeeded launching it programmatically (ins't it?). By knowing that it is possible in some way, I can search for the solution with more confidence. Thank you. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `/usr/include/launch.h`. A quick search revealed [this](http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/2007/10/launchctl-api) link, seems useful.

Comment: The link you provided is dead. can you please explain what you meant by it?

Comment: The page on the link does not exist anymore.

Comment: See launch.h here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/launchd/launchd-328/launchd/src/launch.h